# Given dlib's 68-point facial landmarks, determine how good they are

Tags: computer-vision, face-detection, dlib

I'm using dlib to do face detection, followed by 68-point facial landmark detection. Generally this works very well.

However, dlib's face detector sometimes detects faces where (for example) only one eye is visible, or the person's mouth is not visible (or in rare cases, non-faces). Obviously in these cases some of the 68-points detected are garbage.

How can I detect these cases?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit broad.

In general, the face-detector should have a score to read out. That's one info to use.

Also: after you obtained the landmarks, which are ordered like [this](http://openface-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/dlib-landmark-mean.png), you can:

- check if left-eye is left of right-eye
- eye's are within bounding-box
- eyes above nose / mouth
- ... (you get the idea)

These kind of rules / filterings worked good for me in the past.

Comment: Thank you for the response, these are good suggestions, but I do have some concerns. Firstly, I do not believe that dlib's face detector gives a confidence level. In any case, the problematic cases are indeed faces, so I don't think it's a detection issue: It's just that the faces are at angles such that it's impossible to detect particular landmarks correctly.

Regarding your landmark rules: My concern is that these tests are only valid if the face is aligned. However, if I align based on the landmarks, I may very well normalize-away the problem that I was trying to detect!

Comment: Dlib's face detector can give a confidence score for each detection: see the last few lines of this [example code](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/python_examples/face_detector.py) (from the Dlib Github itself).